# Sum over binary digits of integer

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions

This might seem like a simple enough question but Mathematica seems to simplify inadequately here:
How would you sum over the digits of an arbitrary binary number?
I already tried this:

```
Total[IntegerDigits[j, 2]]
```

which immediately simplifies to an incorrect $j+2$
In fact all

```
Total[IntegerDigits[j, n]]
```

simplify to $j+n$
After that, I tried this:

```
Sum[i, {i, IntegerDigits[j, 2]}]
```

which simplifies to another incorrect

```
1/2 IntegerDigits[j, 2] (1 + IntegerDigits[j, 2])
```

Is there any way, I can prevent these erroreous simplifications?
I need a solution that will work if I use it in another sum which, I ultimately hope, simplifies to something correct.

If you want to see what I need this for, it's for another [now solved problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/242326/49989) on Mathematics StackExchange.

Comment: See if you can wrap it with `Unevaluated`

Comment: @ssch It's hard to be sure wether `Unevaluated` is the reason or it's simply beyond mathematica to solve the posed problem (check the link at the end of the question) but Mathematica can't solve that then. - I tried to solve the same problem with some random cases for c(j) (refering to the link) and mathematica was able to simplify them all. With this solution now, it's stuck with two "Unevaluated"s...

Comment: Have you tried `j - Sum[Quotient[j, 2^k], {k, 1, IntegerLength[j, 2]}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no longer a problem since version 12.0. As mentioned in [this document page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html#447496873):

> Incompatible Changes since Mathematica Version 1
>
> 11.3 to 12.0
>
> `Total` no longer works on expressions with an arbitrary `Head`.

BTW, since version 14.0, you can use `DigitSum` for the task:

```
DigitSum[j, 2] /. j -> 173
(* 5 *)
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

It's easy if you know what to search for. The number of ones in the binary representation of a number is known as its [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight). Searching for "Hamming weight" in the Mathematica documentation leads one to the function [DigitCount](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DigitCount.html), which does exactly what you want:

```
DigitCount[j, 2, 1]
(* DigitCount[j, 2, 1] *)
% /. j -> 173
(* 5 *)
```

Comment: Wish I'd thought of that. :^)

Answer (score 7):

Following Mark's idea you could just use `Tr` which on a vector (simple list) returns the same thing as `Total`, but does not evaluate on an arbitrary head:

```
Tr @ IntegerDigits[j, 2] /. j -> 173
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

Comment: You actually don't need to do `@`. `Tr[IntegerDigits[j,2]]` works too. - That being said, I'm not yet that familiar with the workings of Mathematica, once it comes to pure functions or operators like `@`, so maybe it's somehow advantageous to do that?

Comment: @kram, Wizard here is not very fond of using many brackets, that's all. That being said, `f @ x`, `x // f`, and `f[x]` are three ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: @J.M. Ok, that makes sense. I already knew about the `//` but somehow always was confused by the `@`.

Answer (score 6):

I guess the issue is that `Total` works for arbitrary heads.

```
Total[h[a, b, c]]

(* Out: a + b + c *)
```

You could define a function that sums only lists.

```
listTotal[list_List] := Total[list];
```

Now:

```
Clear[j];
listTotal[IntegerDigits[j, 2]]
j = 22;
listTotal[IntegerDigits[j, 2]]

(* Out:
  listTotal[IntegerDigits[j, 2]]

  3
*)
```

Comment: `Trace` shows that `Total` (no second argument) effectively simply applies `Plus`, replacing whatever head

Comment: @Rojo Not always.Try `list = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {10000000}]; {AbsoluteTiming[Total[list];], AbsoluteTiming[Plus @@ list;]}`.  The `Total` version runs much faster and `Trace` shows no sign of `Plus`. If you set `list=Range[10000]`, though, then `Plus` is applied. Weird, eh?

Comment: I'm not sure what function you used with `Rand` in your last example, but it seems to not apply `Plus` for packed arrays. However, unless it is buggy the behaviour has to be equivalent for packed and non packed I suppose

Comment: @Rojo Oops, my bad. I meant `list=Range[10000]`, which does return a packed array! Of course, the form is much more regular.

Comment: Interesting. In my v8, windows, `Total@Range[10000]` doesn't use `Plus` either

Answer (score 3):

It isn't a closed form or anything, or simpler than `Total[IntegerDigits[j, 2]]`, but here's a representation for the sum of binary digits:

$$s_2(n)=n-\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^{k+1}}\right\rfloor$$

or in *Mathematica* form,

```
BinaryDigitSum[n_] := n - Sum[Quotient[n, 2^k], {k, 1, IntegerLength[n, 2]}]
```