# Module that finds the sum of digits of any given positive integer

Tags: function-construction, summation

How can I make a module that finds the sum of digits of any given positive integer?

I use this command

```
F[x_]:= Apply[ Plus, IntegerDigits[x] ]
```

Is there another module to do it ?

Comment: `Total@IntegerDigits[x]`

Comment: Totlal work as plus ??

Comment: @rola Look in the Mathematica documentation (`F1` button in Mathematica), it is very useful. `Total` is basically the same as `Plus @@ # &` which is the same as `Apply[Plus, #] &`. The main difference, I suppose, is that `Total` allows you to specify the level (for example you can add up all the elements of a matrix, instead of its rows).

Comment: @amr thank you.... but when I have to use module or block . I have to use it like g [n_]:=Module [ ] right!!

Comment: Why do you "have to use Module or Block"?

Comment: @rola please see my answer to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25507/). it's important to understand that Mathematica's syntax is very "raw", in that *there are no keywords*. `Module` is not a keyword. it's a regular symbol/function that you could make your own version of. the important syntax is `:=`, which expects a pattern on the left and basically anything you want on the right. the purpose of `Module` is to create local variables. if you don't need local variables then you don't need `Module`, you can just write the expression, or e.g. `f[x] := (Print[x]; x)`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15137/1871

Answer (score 6):

Mathematical v14.0 introduced [`DigitSum`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/DigitSum.html). For example:

```
DigitSum[2525]
(* 14 *)
```

`DigitSum` threads over lists.

```
DigitSum[{4397, 4268, 782, 2969, 4286}]
(* {23, 20, 17, 26, 20} *)
```

Find the same results with `Total` and `IntegerDigits`:

```
Total[IntegerDigits[2525]]
(* 14 *)

Total /@ IntegerDigits[{4397, 4268, 782, 2969, 4286}]
(* {23, 20, 17, 26, 20} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are other ways.  In *Mathematica* there are usually *many* other ways.

Here is a way using [`DigitCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DigitCount.html) and [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dot.html):

```
f1[n_Integer] := DigitCount[n].{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}

f1[2147]
```

> ```
> 14
> ```

It can be easily extended to bases other than 10:

```
Clear[f1]

f1[n_Integer, b : (_Integer?Positive) : 10] := DigitCount[n, b].Mod[Range[b], b]
```

In base 7:

```
f1[2147, 7]
```

> ```
> 17
> ```

Note that there is no need to use `Module` (or `Block`), and in fact doing so for concise functions is needless clutter.  `Module` should be used when you need localized Symbols, not merely as cruft to wrap every function you write.  `Block` should be used even more selectively as it temporarily modifies global values.  Please see: [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/121)

Also since I assume you are a new *Mathematica* user (and even if you're not) I recommend referencing [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/121).

At some point you may wish to read [How to Combine Pattern Constraints and Default Values for Function Arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4937/121) for an understanding of the second parameter pattern I used in the extended definition of `f1`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
NumberDecompose[2525, {1000, 100, 10, 1}]//Total

(* 14 *)
```

Or

```
NumberDecompose[2525, {1000, 100, 10, 1}] // NumberCompose[#, {1, 1, 1, 1}] &

(* 14 *)
```

Comment: `f = Total@
    NumberDecompose[#, Reverse@PowerRange[1, 10^Floor@Log10@#]] &;`

Answer (score 3):

```
f = Total @ ToExpression @ DeleteCases["-"] @ Characters @ ToString @ # &;

f @ 2147
```

> 14

```
f /@ {-4, 0, 4, 44, 444}
```

> {4, 0, 4, 8, 12}

Answer (score 2):

```
dsum[n_] := Last@Accumulate[IntegerDigits[n]]
```

*Test:*

```
{#, dsum @#} & /@ RandomInteger[{500, 4000}, 5] // Column
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
f = # /. x_ :> Plus @@ ToExpression@Characters[ToString[Abs@x]] &;

f@2147
```

> 14

```
f /@ {-4, 0, 4, 44, 444}
```

> {4, 0, 4, 8, 12}