# How can I find the sum of the even digits of a number of all elements of a list?

Tags: numerics

Let $E(n)$ denote the sum of the even digits of $n$. For example, $E(123456789) = 2 + 4 + 6 + 8$. I tried

```
a = IntegerDigits[123456789]
```

and

```
Total[Select[a, EvenQ]]
```

Now, I want to find the sum $$S= E(1)+ E(2)+\cdots + E(2014).$$ I tried

```
tab = Table[i, {i, 2014}]
```

With the 2012-th, I tried

```
Total[Select[IntegerDigits[tab[[2012]]], EvenQ]]
```

But, I do not how to find the sum $S$. How can I do it with *Mathematica*?

Comment: Strangely coincidental timing with [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39122/121).  Is this part of an assignment?

Comment: From prior questions I know you are not unfamiliar with writing a function in *Mathematica*.  Why not define `Total[Select[IntegerDigits[number], EvenQ]]` as a function `f` and then use `Sum[f[n], {n, 1, 2014}]`?

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tr = Total@Range[2, 8, 2] (*tr == 20*)

e[kkkk_, mmmm_] :=
 mmmm (tr*kkkk*10^(kkkk - 1)) + 10^kkkk*Total@Range[2, mmmm - 1, 2] + 
  Function[If[EvenQ@#, #, 0]]@mmmm

bigE[num_] :=
 Block[{digits = IntegerDigits[num], len}
  ,
  len = Length@digits;
  Total[e @@@ Transpose[{Range[0, len - 1], Reverse@digits}]] + 
   Total[Function[xx, If[EvenQ@xx, xx, 0]][First[#]]*
       FromDigits[Rest@#] & /@ Table[digits[[k ;;]], {k, len}]]
  ]

bigE[2014]
```

> 12056

Don't stare directly at it :P

**Timing comparison**

```
n = 123234;
With[{temp = Flatten[IntegerDigits /@ Range[n]]}, 
  Total@Pick[temp, Mod[temp, 2], 0]] // Timing
Total[f /@ Range[n]] // Timing
bigE[n]//Timing
```

> {0.300975, 1187426}
>   {1.167729, 1187426}
>   {0.000194, 1187426}

also

```
bigE[123123347173459139491384] // Timing
```

> {0.000700, 80816022876813366372150943062694366}

Comment: The `e@@@Tranpose[Range[],...]` thingy is very much like `MapIndexed[e, ...]`

Comment: Very instructive code for me.

Comment: @ubpdqn thanks, that's nice to hear :)

Comment: Jacob, this is the kind of optimization that comes in handy with [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) problems.  Have you tried your hand at those?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ah yes, I should try some of those soon :). I have done one or two problems years ago. I must say comments I saw by you as well as your profile have been a good reminder of the project. But this tipped me over the edge, I have just made an account again :).

Comment: @Jacob Good luck!  I think you'll enjoy it.  We can link accounts to see which problems each other has solved (to know what is fair to talk about etc.) if you are interested.  The problems trend towards getting harder as you go up and I got stumped a few years ago around the time I found Stack Overflow.  I keep meaning to give it another go but something always draws my interest away.

Answer (score 3):

maybe not what you had in mind, but not so slow either:

```
With[{temp = Flatten[IntegerDigits /@ Range[n]]}, 
     Total@Pick[temp, Mod[temp, 2], 0]]
```

Comment: Good start (+1).  This is somewhat shorter and faster:  `#.(1 - Mod[#, 2]) & @ Flatten @ IntegerDigits @ Range @ n`

Comment: nice one - I tried to keep it readable up to some point, as I currently have no time to comment really :) but I like `Dot` there!

Comment: Okay, how about:  `#.Boole[EvenQ@#] & @ Flatten @ IntegerDigits @ Range @ n` ?  Not as fast but perhaps more readable.

Comment: No, that's not worth it, as it's not much faster than the more direct: `Tr @ Select[Flatten @ IntegerDigits @ Range @ n, EvenQ]`

Comment: yes, here I have `Dot`>`Mine`>`Boole`>`Tr`approach in timings, for `n=10^6`

Answer (score 1):

```
f[n_] := Total@Cases[IntegerDigits[n], _?EvenQ]
Total[f /@ Range[2014]]
```

yields:

12056