# Speeding up the built-in Rudin-Shapiro and Thue-Morse sequence functions

Tags: performance-tuning, number-theory, integer-sequence

Version 10.2 introduced two well-studied sequences as functions: the [(Golay-)Rudin-Shapiro sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rudin-ShapiroSequence.html) (`RudinShapiro[]`) and the [(Prouhet-)Thue-Morse sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Thue-MorseSequence.html) (`ThueMorse[]`). Since these functions are defined in terms of the bits of an integer, one would expect these functions to evaluate very fast through low-level bit operations.

Out of curiosity, I had a few volunteers do some tests on these two functions, and it would seem that they are not quite as fast as one would like, thus violating my assumption that these were implemented at bit level.

So: are there more efficient implementations of these two functions?

Comment: I find that `RudinShapiro` takes the same amount of time as Eric Weisstein's high-level implementation. One might assume they are the same.

Comment: `Mod[Total[IntegerDigits[n, 2]], 2]` seems to be faster than `ThueMorse`.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries what is that implementation? From where do you find this?

Comment: @Oleksandr, it's in the notebook in the MathWorld entry I linked to, I believe.

Comment: @OleksandrR. what J. M. says. BTW it differs from the apparently actual implementation in your post.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't download the notebook since I assumed the content was the same as the web page. It is `rudinShapiroEWW[n_Integer] := (-1)^
  Count[Partition[IntegerDigits[n, 2], 2, 1], {1, 1}]`. On my computer this is about 5 times slower than the version 10.2 built-in, and it uses more memory, as one would expect.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I can't take much credit for this answer--I hadn't even got version 10.2 installed until [J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/guess-who-it-is) [commented to me](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87486/faster-binary-hamming-weight-for-big-integers/87498#comment243951_87498) that these functions could be written efficiently in terms of the [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) function. But, it is understandable that he doesn't want to write an answer using a smartphone.

The definition of the built-in `ThueMorse` is:

```
ThueMorse[n_Integer] := Mod[DigitCount[n, 2, 1], 2]
```

And, sure enough, the performance of `DigitCount` used in this way is exactly what [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) [complained about](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87486/faster-binary-hamming-weight-for-big-integers) previously. Let's re-define it to use the `hammingWeight` LibraryLink function given in the linked answer:

```
hammingWeightC = LibraryFunctionLoad[
  "hammingWeight.dll",
  "hammingWeight_T_I", {{Integer, 1, "Constant"}}, {Integer, 0, Automatic}
  ];
hammingWeight[num_Integer] := hammingWeightC@IntegerDigits[num, 2^62];

thueMorse[n_Integer] := Mod[hammingWeight[n], 2]
```

The performance is considerably improved, at least for large numbers:

```
test = 10^(10^5);
ThueMorse[test] // RepeatedTiming (* -> 0.00184271 seconds *)
thueMorse[test] // RepeatedTiming (* -> 0.0000230804 seconds *)
```

That's 80 times faster.

The definition of the built-in `RudinShapiro` is:

```
RudinShapiro[n_Integer] := (-1)^StringCount[IntegerString[n, 2], "11", Overlaps -> True]
```

It is a little strange, in my opinion, to implement the function quite so literally. It can also be written in terms of `ThueMorse` as:

```
rudinShapiro[n_Integer] := 1 - 2 ThueMorse[BitAnd[n, Quotient[n, 2]]]
```

Where the `ThueMorse` used here is still the built-in version. Its performance is fairly improved as a result of this rewriting (which, again, I do not take any credit for):

```
test = 10^(10^5);
RudinShapiro[test] // RepeatedTiming (* -> 0.0131471 seconds *)
rudinShapiro[test] // RepeatedTiming (* -> 0.00195247 seconds *)
```

So, it's almost 7 times faster just by avoiding the use of string functions. What about the case if we also use the improved `thueMorse`?

```
rudinShapiro2[n_Integer] := 1 - 2 thueMorse[BitAnd[n, Quotient[n, 2]]]

test = 10^(10^5);
rudinShapiro2[test] // RepeatedTiming (* -> 0.0000490027 seconds *)
```

This revision is 270 times faster than the built-in version. If its timing only depended on `thueMorse`, it would be about $7 \times 80 = 560$ times faster. The fact that it comes within a factor of 2 of this limit suggests that `BitAnd` and `Quotient` are quite efficient.

But, `Quotient` still isn't *quite* as efficient as a bit shift (again, not my idea):

```
rudinShapiro3[n_Integer] := 1 - 2 thueMorse[BitAnd[n, BitShiftRight[n]]];

test = 10^(10^5);
rudinShapiro3[test] // RepeatedTiming (* -> 0.0000314508 seconds *)
```

Now it's 420 times faster than the built-in.

Here I will just take the opportunity to remind anyone from WRI who may read this that all of the code in my answers is offered under academic-style permissive licences (your choice of three). So, it should be possible to speed up these functions in the product with minimal effort and without need to write any new code.

Comment: Replacing `Quotient[n, 2]` with `BitShiftRight[n]` does not make much of a difference, right?

Comment: @J.M. I would not have thought it would do. But it is a good idea, and sure enough, it actually does make a significant difference. Post updated.

Comment: Now that was a surprise… thanks!

Comment: In that case… what if you replace `Mod[n, 2]` with `BitAnd[n, 1]`?

Comment: @J.M. That will have to wait till later, I'm afraid. But I doubt it will make any significant difference, given that the value being `Mod`ed is just a machine-size integer.

Comment: That's okay… you've been more than helpful. :)

Comment: @J.M., I've tried your suggestion (replacing `Mod` with `BitAnd`), there's no noticeable difference on my machine.

Comment: @Runny, I knew I'd be asking to squeeze water from stones at some point; thanks for trying!

Answer (score 7):

With modest preprocessing we get a factor of 9 or so for large inputs just by chunking into 12 bit pieces and using a compiled lookup function.

```
m = 12;
Timing[tmLookup = 
   Table[Mod[Total[IntegerDigits[j, 2]], 2], {j, 0, 2^m - 1}];]

(* Out[49]= {0.00157, Null} *)
```

Some of the option settings are probably overkill.

```
tmLookupCSmall = With[{tmtable = tmLookup}, Compile[
    {{bigits, _Integer, 1}},
    Mod[Total[Map[tmtable[[# + 1]] &, bigits]], 2], 
    RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]];
```

Here is the large test from a prior response.

```
In[45]:= test = 10^(10^5);

In[46]:= Timing[Do[ThueMorse[test], {1000}];]

(* Out[46]= {0.912775, Null} *)

In[51]:= Timing[Do[tmLookupCSmall[IntegerDigits[test, 2^m]], {1000}];]

(* Out[51]= {0.11619, Null} *)

In[52]:= tm1 === tm2

(* Out[52]= True *)
```

There are two bottlenecks. One is that we cannot really take the chunk size much higher since we have to store `2^m` values for chunks of `m` bits. Another is that the compiling to `C` is probably well below optimal in terms of run time efficiency. I have not tried using larger sizes and reimplementing in bitwise operations so possibly that could give a further boost.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that the compiler builtins are very fast and don't depend on the existence of the POPCNT instruction, so it is not necessary to use the lookup table. My home computer, for example, doesn't have it. I am actually not sure how the CRTs do it--maybe they indeed use a LUT, but it is surprisingly fast if so. If a `HammingWeight` function were implemented, it would be a very good building block for all sorts of other functions, of which this seems a good example. Better if it would not be necessary to use `IntegerDigits`, but this is of course a constraint of LibraryLink.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to define the sequence recursively:

```
t[0] = 0;
t[n_] := t[n] = If[EvenQ[n], t[n/2], 1 - t[(n-1)/2]];
```

To check:

```
t[#] & /@ Range[100] == ThueMorse[Range[100]]
True
```

For speed:

```
ThueMorse[Range[20000]]; // AbsoluteTiming
{0.45703, Null}

t[#] & /@ Range[20000]; // AbsoluteTiming
{0.095282, Null}
```

Attempting to fine tune this leads to only small improvements:

```
tb[0] = 0;
tb[n_] := tb[n] = (tN = tb[BitShiftRight[n, 1]]; If[EvenQ[n], tN, 1 - tN]);
```

Sorry for being so late to the ThueMorse party!

Comment: Can you add timings comparing the recursive implementation with the built-in? Also, it might be quicker to use `Quotient[]` instead of dividing with `/` (or even go further and use `BitShiftRight[]`).

Comment: @bills Have you tried `t[10^(10^5)]`?