# Most efficient way to define evil and odious numbers

Tags: function-construction, number-theory, algorithm

A positive integer $n$ is defined to be **evil** if the number of ones in its binary expansion is even, otherwise it is **odious**. Now define the function
$$
\begin{equation*}
t(n)=
  \begin{cases}
  1 \rm{ \ if \ n \ is \ evil, } \\
        0 \rm{ \ if \ n \ is \ odious. } \\
  \end{cases} 
  \end{equation*}
$$
The sequence associated with the function $t(n)$ is often referred to as the Thue-Morse sequence.

What is the best/most efficient way to write the function $t(n)$ in Mathematica?

Comment: [A related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89345).

Comment: Are you aware that `ThueMorse` is a built-in function? Is there some reason why you need to define your own version? Like is this homework?

Comment: @m_goldberg No I wasn't, I just discovered it in the link posted by the above user.

Comment: Using [`FindSequenceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html), Mathematica will tell you about the built-in [`ThueMorse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ThueMorse.html) function. 

`FindSequenceFunction[{#, 
    OddQ@Total@IntegerDigits[#, 2] /. {True -> 1, False -> 0}} & /@ 
  Range[0, 10], n]` evaluates to 

`ThueMorse[n]`